# Javascript/Jquery - Reset text box view area after tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, input

I don't know what this is called so its hard to google for it.

If you have a plain html input type=text with a small width eg 20 and then type more characters than can be displayed, it shows the last characters you type. And the first ones are scrolled out of view:

```
This is my long text // this is the whole string
my long string // this is what is actually visible in the input box
```

How do I make it so that when you hit tab, the view area resets so that the start of the string is visible and the end is hidden?

```
my long string // this is what is visible in the input box when typing
This is my // this is what is I want to be visible in the input box after you hit tab
```

What do you call this, and how do you do it?

Comment: Sorry @JK, I failed you.  I have removed my answer.  Even so you might want to re-ask as this question may now be a little stale.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question has been answered, but I just felt like answering myself. You can do it by using ranges and window selection. [Here, I made a JSFiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/RcG4X/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").bind("keyup",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==9){
        var r=document.createRange(),
        gs=getSelection();
        r.setStart(this,0);r.setEnd(this,0);
        gs.removeAllRanges();gs.addRange(r);
    }
  });
  $("input").bind("blur"),function(){
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```